# Arabic language sounding differently in windows speech synthesis

Tags: javascript

The output of windows speech syntheis for arabic language is not similar to google translator's output. What should be done??

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();    
var lang1="ar" 
msg.voice =voices[2]; 
msg.lang=lang1; 
msg.text = "يرجى نسخ الجملة التالية أدناه";    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Comment: What do you expect an answer to be, should we hack the Google translation according to speechSynthesis, or vice versa?

Comment: The output i.e pronunciation of windows speech synthesis for Arabic language should be same as that of the google translator. (PS : It is coming exactly the same for other languages. Only Arabic is giving issues)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've to write to your browser vendor, it's unlikely, that we here at SO could fix the pronunciation ...

Answer (score 0):

this is because html charset is not supported for this.

Please add this line at the top of your head tag.

```
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

This will work.