# speechsynthesisutterance doesn't read arabic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, speech-synthesis

I wanted to implement a tex to speech on my web app, I tested it on other languages (french and english)
and the text converted to speech just fine ,but when i set the language to arabic

```
utterThis.lang = 'ar-AE';
```

I hear nothing, doesnt javascript detect arabic letters?

here is the code i tried

```
 const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
 const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(resultText);

const speechHandler = () => {
        utterThis.lang = 'ar-AE';
        synth.speak(utterThis);
       
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lang` property accepts a BCP 47 language tag, according to the Mozilla Developer Network ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/lang)).

I'm not too familiar with BCP 47 language tags, but it looks like `ar-AE` is an ISO language code whereas `ar-SA` is the only Arabic BCP 47 language tag.

Comment: thanks for this notice,but it still doesnt work ,whenever i set it to ```ar-SA``` it reads the text with a french accent (wich is the default language i assume)

Comment: @drdarkfrancis - Does the answer in this thread help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53774437/1920035

Comment: nope still nothing

Comment: @drdarkfrancis - If you call `synth.getVoices()` do any of them come back where the lang is `ar`?